# Which is the best viable operator == function between these two declarations?

Tags: c++, templates, language-lawyer, c++20

```cpp
#include <iostream>
template<typename T>
struct A{};
struct Y{
    template<typename T>
    bool operator==(A<T>){
        std::cout<<"#1\n";
        return true;
    }
};
template<typename T>
bool operator==(T,Y){
    std::cout<<"#2\n";
    return true;
}
int main(){ 
    A<int> a;
    Y y;
    a==y;
}
```

For the above snippet, GCC prints `#2` while Clang prints `#1`. The result is [here](https://godbolt.org/z/fcWb6E). I think Clang is right, since `#2` is a non-rewritten non-member candidate for the expression `a==y`. Instead, the synthesized candidate for `#1` is also a viable function. That is, the overload set would consist of two candidates, which look like:

```cpp
#1'
bool operator==(A<int>,Y); [with T = int] // synthesized candidate for #1

#2'
bool operator==(A<int>,Y);[with T = A<int>]
```

According to [temp.func.order#3](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/temp.func.order#3)

> If exactly one of the function templates was considered by overload resolution via a rewritten candidate ([over.match.oper]) with a reversed order of parameters, then the order of the function parameters **in its transformed template is reversed**.

The P/A pairs are the following:

```cpp
transformed type for #1: (A<uniqueT1>, Y) as A
original type for #2: (T, Y)  as P

transformed type for #2: (UniqueT2, Y) as A
original type for #1: (Y, A<UniqueT1>) as P
```

For the above candidates, the template function's partial ordering is sufficient to determine which is the best viable. which is bullet [over.match.best#2.5](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/over.match.best#2.5)

> for some argument j, ICSj(F1) is a better conversion sequence than ICSj(F2), or, if not that,
>
> > 2.5 F1 and F2 are function template specializations, and the function template for F1 is more specialized than the template for F2 according to the partial ordering rules described in [temp.func.order], or, **if not that**,
> > [2.6 - 2.7]
> > 2.8 F2 is a rewritten candidate ([over.match.oper]) and F1 is not

That means that it's not necessary to step into bullet 2.8. According to the above P/A pairs, `#1` is at least as specialized as `#2` but `#2` is not at least as specialized as `#1`; Hence, `#1'` is the best viable candidate in partial ordering. So, Clang should be correct here.

However, consider the following variant snippet

```cpp
#include <iostream>
template<class T>
struct A{};

class Y{};

template<class T>
bool operator==(Y,A<T>){
    std::cout<<"#1\n";
    return true;
}

template<class T>
bool operator ==(T,Y){
    std::cout<<"#2\n";
    return true;
}

int main(){
   A<int> a;
   Y y{};
   a == y;
}
```

At this time, Both Clang and GCC agree that `#2` is the best viable candidate. The result is [here](https://godbolt.org/z/PhvqWe). However, it appears to me that this example is similar to the first. Merely, it changes the member candidate to be a non-member candidate. Again, the overload set would consist of two candidates, which look like:

```cpp
#1''
bool operator==(A<int>,Y); [with T = int]  // synthesized candidate for #1

#2''
bool operator==(A<int>,Y); [with T = A<int>]
```

In this example, partial ordering is also sufficient to determine which candidate is the best. Hence, `#1''` still should be the best. Why do Clang and GCC both think #2 is the best in this example?

Comment: When compiler executes line "a==y", I guess it would check with prototype 
1. "<a object>.==(y object)" for your first example
2."==(<a object>, <y object>) for your second example, since the 1st prototype is not present
I guess that is making the #2 candidate as the best function to be executed in both your examples

Comment: @SantoshSahu c++20 introduced a new concept for equality operations, which is a rewritten candidate, which make `x==y` that was ill-formed in c++17 to be well-formed in c++20 if there's a candidate for the expression `y==x`.

Comment: I think they probably haven't implemented CWG2445.

Comment: @T.C. The first example seems that Clang has implemented that proposal. However, For the second example, whereas Clang reflects that it does not.

Comment: @T.C. Clang has the right implementation of the [example](https://godbolt.org/z/qqxo78) of cwg2445. However, I don't know why Clang selects `#2` for the second example in my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer: You used different Clang versions in your examples, Clang 11 has a correct implementation, while Clang 10 does not.

In my answer I go into detail why Clang 11 and MSVC are right and GCC is wrong in both cases.

---

From [[over.match.oper]#3](https://eel.is/c++draft/over.match.oper#3) the candidates include four sets:

> For [...] a binary operator `@` [...] four sets of candidate functions, designated *member candidates*, *non-member candidates*, *built-in candidates*, and *rewritten candidates*, are constructed as follows:

In your case the rewritten candidates are determined by [[over.match.oper]#3.4.4](https://eel.is/c++draft/over.match.oper#3.4.4):

> For the equality operators, the rewritten candidates also include a synthesized candidate, with the order of the two parameters reversed, for each non-rewritten candidate for the expression `y == x`.

In your case for an expression `x == y` the candidates of interest are:

- *member candidates*: candidates for `x.operator==(y)`
- *non-member candidates*: candidates for `operator==(x, y)`
- *rewritten candidates*: non-rewritten candidates for `y == x`, which are `y.operator==(x)` and `operator==(y, x)`.

Let's look at your two examples and determine the best candidate.

---

### First example

For the expression `a == y` the candidates are:

```
non-rewritten candidates:
    #2 via operator==(a, y)
rewritten candidates:
    #1 via y.operator==(a)
```

To determine the better candidate we need to apply [[over.match.best.general]#2](https://eel.is/c++draft/over.match.best.general#2), the relevant rules to determine if `F1` is a better match than `F2` are:

> [(2.5)](https://eel.is/c++draft/over.match.best.general#2.5)  `F1` and `F2` are function template specializations, and the function template for `F1` is more specialized than the template for `F2` according to the partial ordering rules described in [temp.func.order], or, if not that,
>
> [...]
>
> [(2.8)](https://eel.is/c++draft/over.match.best.general#2.8)  `F2` is a rewritten candidate ([over.match.oper]) and `F1` is not

If we take `#1` to be `F1` and `#2` to be `F2` we get that `#1` is a better match, since [(2.5)](https://eel.is/c++draft/over.match.best.general#2.5) applies and it's considered before [(2.8)](https://eel.is/c++draft/over.match.best.general#2.8).  Clang 11+ and the latest MSVC correctly select `#1` as the better candidate here ([demo](https://godbolt.org/z/Ps3h47zne)).

---

### Second example

For the expression `a == y` the candidates are:

```
non-rewritten candidates:
    #2 via operator==(a, y)
rewritten candidates:
    #1 via operator==(y, a)
```

Applying [[over.match.best.general]#2](https://eel.is/c++draft/over.match.best.general#2) and taking `#1` to be `F1` and `#2` to be `F2`, similarly to the first example we get that `#1` is a better candidate since [(2.5)](https://eel.is/c++draft/over.match.best.general#2.5) applies and it's considered before [(2.8)](https://eel.is/c++draft/over.match.best.general#2.8).  Same as in the first example Clang 11+ and the latest MSVC correctly select `#1` as the better candidate ([demo](https://godbolt.org/z/Ps3h47zne)).

> Why do Clang and GCC both think #2 is the best in this example?

The don't.  In your demo link you used Clang 10, while in the first example you used Clang 11.  Clang 10 has the same result as GCC in both cases.

---

In both cases `#1` is the better candidate, which Clang 11+ and the latest MSVC correctly select.  GCC fails in both cases, selecting `#2`.  My guess would be that GCC's implementation of [[over.match.best.general]#2](https://eel.is/c++draft/over.match.best.general#2) is incorrect in that it wrongly consideres [(2.8)](https://eel.is/c++draft/over.match.best.general#2.8) before [(2.5)](https://eel.is/c++draft/over.match.best.general#2.5) and selects the non-rewritten candidate in both cases.

Comment: @IICapitano *You used different Clang versions in your examples, Clang 11 has a correct implementation, while Clang 10 does not.* Thanks, that resolved all my confusion.